# Windows media foundation 2D Buffer

Tags: video, ms-media-foundation

I am having issues understanding in what instance `IMF2DBuffer` is available for use. Using `QueryInterface` on `IMFMediaBuffer` results in `No such interface supported`. (I am using Windows 10.)

I found this wording but it's very vague:

> This interface is designed specifically for image data. To get a
>   pointer to this interface, call QueryInterface on the media buffer.
>   **Not all media buffer objects expose this interface.** But if a media buffer does expose the IMF2DBuffer interface, you should use that
>   interface to access the data, if possible, rather than using
>   IMFMediaBuffer. You can still use the IMFMediaBuffer interface, but it
>   might be less efficient.

I can't find any information on in what cases it does or doesn't expose this. Does it rely on the media? The output format? The codec? OS version? It really doesn't say.

Answer (score 1):

The language of the quote suggests the way you should approach to using this interface. You should not rely on media, output format, codec or OS version.

The idea is that "sometimes" you can have this interface for more efficient data access. So if you want to fine tune processing, you could have one code path that does `IMF2DBuffer` and fallback codec path for generic `IMFMediaBuffer`.

This is the documentation message, which makes reasonable sense.

Availability of `IMF2DBuffer` is implementation specific. There is no direct mention when it is available because it is a promise: if it is documented then there is a promise to follow that, there is no reason to take such a constraint.

The documentation for the interface itself explains that this interface helps when the data is effectively stored in a no-standard way. `IMFMediaBuffer` access will have to rearrange the data, which might be not so much efficient performance wise. `IMF2DBuffer` methods in turn help to do certain tasks/data access without "expensive" data re-arrangement.

Comment: Also, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfobjects/nf-mfobjects-imfmediabuffer-lock reads: `... This method [IMFMediaBuffer] may internally allocate some memory, so if the buffer supports the IMF2DBuffer interface, you should use the IMF2DBuffer::Lock2D method to lock the buffer instead. ...`. It may or may not support.

Comment: Adding to this, the methods Lock/Unlock are not implemented for a media buffer you got from the media sample (`pSample->GetBufferByIndex(0, &mediaBuffer)`): hr = mediaBuffer->Lock(&pbBuffer, &maxLen, &currLen); results in hr = E_NOTIMPL. GetMaxLength(..) is not implemented, too, although Microsoft's Media Foundation documentation is silent on the fact. Only GetCurrentLength(..) is implemented.